# incremental update with symfony/propel

Tags: php, database, symfony1, propel

I would like execute a query like this one in symfony using the Propel ORM:

```
UPDATE ADS SET HITS=HITS+1 WHERE ID=10;
```

I know that Propel API can let me set a previously fixed value for a column of a given record, but I definitely don't want to retrieve the column value first before issuing an update query since there are  concurrent access.

Please, how could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Symfony 1.3/1.4:

in AdsPeer:

```
public static function incrementHits($id)
{
  $con = Propel::getConnection(AdsPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
  $query = 'UPDATE hits SET hits + 1 WHERE id = '.$id;
  sfContext::getInstance()->getLogger()->crit($query);
  $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
  $rs = $stmt->execute();
}
```

To use:

```
AdsPeer::incrementHits($id);
```

HTH

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can do a [Select using SQL](http://propel.phpdb.org/docs/user_guide/chapters/FindingObjects.html) in propel.

Here's an example:

```
class BookPeer extends BaseBookPeer {
  .
  .
  .
  /**
   * Get just the Books that have not been reviewed.
   * @return array Book[]
   */
  function getUnreviewedBooks() {
    $con = Propel::getConnection(DATABASE_NAME);

    // if not using a driver that supports sub-selects
    // you must do a cross join (left join w/ NULL)
    $sql = "SELECT books.* FROM books WHERE ".
           "NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM review WHERE book_id = book.id)";

    $stmt = $con->createStatement();
    $rs = $stmt->executeQuery($sql, ResultSet::FETCHMODE_NUM);

    return parent::populateObjects($rs);    
  }
```

You can try this with `update` as well.